# the commutant of $\mathcal{HS(H)}$

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $\mathcal{HS}(H)$ be the set of Hilber Schmidt operators on a Hilbert space,it is a $C^*$ algebra.I wonder whether we have an explicit description of the commutant of  $\mathcal{HS(H)}$.Is the commutant of $\mathcal{HS(H)}$ closed in $B(H)$?

Comment: $\mathcal H\mathcal S(H)$ is not a $C^*$-algebra though, with respect to any norm, let alone $HS$ norm. !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any set $S\subset B(H)$, the commutant of $S$ equals the commutant of the operator norm closure of $S$.  Since the operator norm closure of $\mathcal{HS}(H)$ is $K(H)$, the commutant of $\mathcal{HS}(H)$ equals the commutant of $K(H)$, which is $\mathbb C$.